# Javascript - .getHours() not working

Tags: javascript

I'm just messing around and I'm still relatively new to JavaScript. I wrote this code:

```
<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var str ='';
    str = today.getHours();

    if (str >=5 && str <=10) 
    {
        alert("Wow you're up early!, good morning");
    }
    if (str >= 11 && str <= 1)
    {
        alert("Good Morning");
    }
    if (str >=2 && str <= 21)
    {
        alert("Good evening");
    }
    if(str >= 22 && str <= 4)
    {
        alert("Good night");
    }
```

Basically, the alert box isn't coming up. Though it does come up if I change the `getHours` function to `getUTCHours`. Unfortunately I can't use that because it is one hour behind. So does anyone know why my alert box isn't coming up?

Comment: `str >= 11 && str <= 1` - how can that ever be true? What numbers do you know that are greater than 10 **and** less than 2? Similarly for `str >= 22 && str <= 4`

Comment: Note: This should be `var str = today.getHours()`. Initializing it as an empty string and then replacing that with something else is pointless.

Comment: I just pasted this into a page and it alerted me twice -  the first one and the "good evening". the hours here is 7. It is getting the hours correctly - it is you conditional statements that will need adjusting.

Comment: Oh you're right lol, for some reason my stupid brain thought it was operating under a 24 hour system lol, meaning that after 24, it would loop back to 1

Comment: Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Ken, it is operating with a 24-hour number

Comment: A good way to debug is to add a console.log(str) before the first if statement. Check the output of the console.log and check why it isn't going into any of the if statements

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to be over-specific with your ranges. Also, don't use var names like `str`, especially when the data contained in the var is an integer... That's just extremely confusing

```
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();

if (hour < 5)
  alert('Goodnight');
else if (hour < 10)
  alert("Wow you're up early! Good morning.");
else if (hour < 14)
  alert("Good morning");
else if (hour < 21)
  alert("Good evening");
else
  alert("Goodnight")
```

You're gonna say "that sucks, though", right? Because we have to specify the `"Goodnight"` scenario twice.

That can be easily fixed with an offset though

```
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
hour = hour - 5; // offset

if (hour < 5)
  alert("Wow you're up early! Good morning.")
else if (hour < 9)
  alert("Good morning");
else if (hour < 15)
  alert("Good evening");
else
  alert("Goodnight")
```

Comment: You could also do `if (hour < 5 || hour >= 21) alert('Goodnight');`

Answer (score 0):

because the conditions are wrong: for example, now,  00:00, you would want the message "Good night", but 0 can't be >= 22 and <=4